# How can we reproduce Eugen Jahnke's drawing of a complex function?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, complex, generative-art

Eugen Jahnke (1863 - 1921) studied mathematics and physics at the Humboldt University of Berlin. He became a professor at the Berlin Mining Academy in 1905.

[image]

His *"Tables of Functions with Formulae and Curves"* first appeared in 1909 and was printed into the 1960s (significantly expanded by Fritz Emde after the death of Jahnke). Used copies are still available. The book was a landmark of the visual presentation of mathematical surfaces. It proved popular not only with mathematicians but also with designers and artists.

[image]

*Le Corbusier, Phillips Pavillion, Brussels 1958*

Le Corbusier had a copy in his library when designing the Phillips Pavillion (a cluster of nine hyperbolic paraboloids for the Expo '58 in Brussels), and Max Ernst produced several collages which integrated the functional drawings into surreal contexts.

[image]

*Max Ernst, The Fable of the Mouse of Milo, c.1948*

My aim is to reproduce with Mathematica as faithful as possible Jahnke's drawing of this complex arctan surface:

[image]

The following attempt might be a good starting point,

```
n = 2;
ComplexPlot3D[ArcTan[z], {z, -n - n I, n + n I},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 Boxed -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1] &),
 Exclusions -> None,
 Filling -> Bottom,
 Mesh -> {Join[{0}, Range[0, 2, 0.1]], Range[-Pi, Pi, 2 Pi/24]},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 2.5}},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[1],
 ViewPoint -> {3., 2.4, 3}]
```

[image]

but it lacks some important features, above all the cut-outs.

Comment: `, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 2.5}}
 , PlotStyle -> Glow[White]
 , ImageSize -> 500
 , SphericalRegion -> True
 , RegionFunction -> Function[{z, f}, -\[Pi]/2 <= Arg[z] < \[Pi]]
 , FillingStyle -> {HatchShading[1/2, Black]}
 (*,FillingStyle\[Rule]{HalftoneShading[1/2,Gray,"Line"]}*)
 , Lighting -> "Accent"
 ]`

Comment: Why don't you put this as an answer? Please add `ViewPoint -> {-1.3, -2.4, 2}` and `FillingStyle -> {HalftoneShading[1/4, Gray, "Line"]}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
n = 2;
ComplexPlot3D[ArcTan[z]
 , {z, -n - n I, n + n I}
 , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
 , AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}
 , Boxed -> False
 , ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1] &)
 , Exclusions -> None
 , Filling -> Bottom
 , Mesh -> {Join[{0}, Range[0, 2, 0.1]]
   , Range[-Pi, Pi, 2 Pi/24]}
 , PlotPoints -> 50
 , PlotRange -> {{-n, n}, {-n, n}, {0, 1.5 n}}
 , PlotStyle -> Glow[White]
 , ImageSize -> 500
 , SphericalRegion -> True
 , ViewPoint -> {-1.3, -2.4, 2}
 , RegionFunction -> Function[{z}, -π/2 <= Arg[z] < π]
 , FillingStyle -> {HalftoneShading[1/4, Gray, "Line"]}
 , Lighting -> "Accent"
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

- Try to simulate the effects of lighting.
- The light from `lighting = {3, .2, 2};` seems work fine.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_] := Abs@ArcTan[x + I*y];
F[{x_, y_}] := {x, y, f[x, y]};
face[pt1_, pt2_][t_, 
  s_] := {1 - s, 
   s} . {PadRight[#, 3] &@Most@F[{1 - t, t} . {pt1, pt2}], 
   F[{1 - t, t} . {pt1, pt2}]}
pts = {{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4.5, -.5}, {5, -1.5}, {0, -6}, {-6, 0}, {-1.5,
     5}, {-.5, 4.5}, {0, 4}};
L = .2;
lighting = {3, .2, 2};
plot1 = Function[{pt1, pt2}, 
    ParametricPlot3D[
     face[pt1, pt2][t, s] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
     Mesh -> With[{λ = 
         Abs@Sin@VectorAngle[Cross[pt2 - pt1], 
            Most@lighting]}, {Flatten@
         Table[{k*L - λ*L/2, k*L + λ*L/2}/
           EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2], {k, 0, 
           1 + Ceiling[(EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2] - λ*L/2)/
              L]}]}], MeshShading -> {White, Black}, Boxed -> False, 
     Axes -> False]] @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1];
plot2 = Plot3D[Abs@ArcTan[x + I*y], {x, y} ∈ Polygon[pts], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   Boxed -> False, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, Function[{x, y}, Arg@ArcTan[x + I*y]]}, 
   Mesh -> 15, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 2.5}}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Glow@White];

Show[plot2, plot1, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
 ViewPoint -> {8, 8, 8}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Original**

- We again using `Plot3D` to plot `Abs@ArcTan[x + I*y]` and set the `MeshFunction` to be `{#3 &, Arg[ArcTan[#1 + I*#2]] &}` (Or maybe `{Abs@ArcTan[#1 + I*#2] &, Im@ArcTan[#1 + I*#2] &}`)
- Cut the plot by `Polygon[{{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, -1}, {3, -2}, {0, -4}, {-4, 0}, {-2, 3}, {-1, 4}, {0, 4}}]`.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, -1}, {3, -2}, {0, -4}, {-4, 0}, {-2, 
    3}, {-1, 4}, {0, 4}};
Plot3D[Abs@ArcTan[x + I*y], {x, y} ∈ Polygon[pts], 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 Boxed -> False, Exclusions -> None, Filling -> Bottom, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, Arg[ArcTan[#1 + I*#2]] &}, Mesh -> 15, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 2.5}}, 
 ViewPoint -> {8, 8, 8}, Axes -> False, 
 FillingStyle -> 
  Directive@{Black, Opacity[1], HatchShading[.6, White]}, 
 Lighting -> "Accent", PlotStyle -> Glow[White]]
```

[image]

- Another trying.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4.5, -.5}, {5, -1.5}, {0, -6}, {-6, 0}, {-1.5,
     5}, {-.5, 4.5}, {0, 4}};
reg = Plot3D[Abs@ArcTan[x + I*y], {x, y} ∈ Polygon[pts], 
    PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 5}}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 80, 
    MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotStyle -> None, Filling -> Bottom, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False] // DiscretizeGraphics;
plot1 = RegionPlot3D[reg, Mesh -> {200, 100}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Lighting -> "Accent", 
   PlotStyle -> White];
plot2 = Plot3D[Abs@ArcTan[x + I*y], {x, y} ∈ Polygon[pts], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   Boxed -> False, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, Function[{x, y}, Arg@ArcTan[x + I*y]]}, 
   Mesh -> 15, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 2.5}}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Glow@White];
Graphics3D[{{plot2[[1]], plot1[[1]]}}, Lighting -> "Accent", 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {8, 8, 8}]
```

[image]

- `MeshShading`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_] := Abs@ArcTan[x + I*y];
F[{x_, y_}] := {x, y, f[x, y]};
face[pt1_, pt2_][t_, 
  s_] := {1 - s, 
   s} . {PadRight[#, 3] &@Most@F[{1 - t, t} . {pt1, pt2}], 
   F[{1 - t, t} . {pt1, pt2}]}
pts = {{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4.5, -.5}, {5, -1.5}, {0, -6}, {-6, 0}, {-1.5,
     5}, {-.5, 4.5}, {0, 4}};
plot1 = ParametricPlot3D[
   face[#1, #2][t, s] & @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1] // Evaluate, {t, 
    0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{# - 1/60, # + 1/60} & /@ Subdivide[0, 1, 20] // Flatten},
    MeshShading -> {Black, White}, BoundaryStyle -> Gray];
plot2 = Plot3D[Abs@ArcTan[x + I*y], {x, y} ∈ Polygon[pts], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   Boxed -> False, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, Function[{x, y}, Arg@ArcTan[x + I*y]]}, 
   Mesh -> 15, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 2.5}}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Glow@White];
Show[plot2, plot1, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
 ViewPoint -> {8, 8, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, cvgmt, for your excellent answer(s). This time I particularly like how you do the cutouts (I've never this polygon-cut before).

Comment: @eldo How to adjust the mesh shading similar with the  effect of light seems not so easy. I can not find out a way.